# Drupal 7 Views - customize RSS output template

Tags: view, themes, drupal-7

I have RSS feed of custom type news items in Drupal 7 using Views module. Created views-view-row-rss.tpl.php in /mytheme/ directory and in "Edit view" "Theming information" Row style output: views-view-row-rss.tpl.php shows that template was found in my themes directory. Problem is, that this template is not used, RSS feed is always generated using default template. And clicking on Row style displays default template. How to force Views module to use my custom template?

Comment: Yes, I cleared out Drupal and Views caches.

Comment: So I actually done an override for mythere_preprocess_views_view_row_rss() function in template.php to rewrite RSS output. Not the most elegant way, but it worked.

Comment: what you just did is correct since there's no way yet that you can add/format rss output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put a specific filename like what you see in the theme info in views.
Say for example if you have a 'sales' feed as view.

The template files according to theme information:
**views-view-row-rss--sales--feed.tpl.php
views-view-rss--sales--feed.tpl.php**

Make sure to flush your cache and put the files in your templates folder.
ex. **themes\custom\mytheme\templates**

Answer (score 0):

Don't use views.

Use [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) and pass the nids to [node_feed](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_feed/7).

EFQ is VERY easy to use. Here are [a couple of tutorials](http://treehouseagency.com/category/tags/entityfieldquery).

Answer (score 0):

The correct location for views templates is sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates/views/

Move it there and run a full cache flush and you should see it.